# Can government query company, such as Google, to get list of accounts associated with some information, such as IP address or phone number?

Tags: privacy, legal, government

UPD: My naive thought was that government requests should explicitly point account for which they requesting information. And that a broad requests like getting list of accounts logged during some months from some IP address would be something extraordinary. But now I get that It probably usually works exactly that way about what I previously was thinking as extraordinary case.

---

As I understand, Google Transparency Report describes typical requests from government as:

> Hey, Google, give to us IP addresses associated with account
>   john.doe@gmail.com

This requires government to already know account name for which they want to get information. But how does government can get this account name if all what they know is IP address and time, or phone number, or credit card number? Can government do query like:

> Hey, Google, give to us list of accounts accessed from that IP address
>   at that time

Or:

> Hey, Google, give to us list of accounts that specified this phone number
>   in contact information

Or maybe this is exactly how it's actually work and I just misunderstood some basic principles?

Comment: I'm sure that if a law enforcement agency has a legal request, they can ask for whatever information they require. I'm not sure what you are asking, though. Are you asking what is legally possible, or what is technically possible? Or asking what Google does?

Comment: @schroeder I understand that it's perfectly technically and legally possible, I was thinking on how about it usually looks like in the average case. Now I think I get It, UPD in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read Google's TOS and PP? It says they will divulge any information they deem necessary to comply with any enforceable legal request.

**We will share personal information with companies, organizations or individuals outside of Google if we have a good-faith belief that access, use, preservation or disclosure of the information is reasonably necessary to:

- meet any applicable law, regulation, legal process **or enforceable governmental request.**
- enforce applicable Terms of Service, including investigation of potential violations.
- detect, prevent, or otherwise address fraud, security or technical issues.
- protect against harm to the rights, property or safety of Google, our users or the public as required or permitted by law.**

Full text here: https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/

To answer your question more completely, typically a wide-net request like "Give me all users from IP X.X.X.X from 2015, would be a little too vague for a judge to sign off on. We hope. Get a VPN if you're worried.

Comment: My naive thought was that government requests should explicitly point account for which they requesting information. And that a broad requests like getting list of accounts logged during some months from some IP address would be something extraordinary. But now I get that It probably usually works exactly that way about what I previously was thinking as extraordinary case.